# magento 1.9 show â‚¬ instead of euro symbol on list & product detail page?

Tags: magento

I am using magento 1.9.0.1

i have tried changing language dropdown euro sign not seen properly like â‚¬5.95
 on list & detail page?

Could somebody help? Tried some solutions by searching online, nothing worked.

Comment: What is your `content-type` ?

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: Did you try this `<?php echo mb_convert_encoding($this->__('Sometext'), "UTF-8", "HTML-ENTITIES"); ?>`

Comment: in which file add above code?